# How do I echo my checked checkboxes?

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have names in my database like below...

[image]

With the code below I see these users on my page with a checkbox beside them.

```
 $select_from_user_table = "SELECT  contacts.contact_id, user.username
FROM contacts 
INNER JOIN user
ON contacts.contact_id=user.user_id WHERE contacts.user_id = '$user_id'";

    //get the result of the above
    $result2=mysqli_query($con,$select_from_user_table); 
    //show the usernames, phone numbers
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check_contacts[]' >" . $row['username'] . "<br>";


if(!empty($_POST['check_contacts'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_contacts'] as $check) {
            echo $check; //echoes the value set in the HTML form for each checked checkbox.
                         //so, if I were to check 1, 3, and 5 it would echo value 1, value 3, value 5.
                         //in your case, it would echo whatever $row['Report ID'] is equivalent to.
    }
}
    }
    $con->close();
```

How can I have it so when the checkboxes are checked, the result will be echoed like `Will Shakespeare John Grisham` if those names are checked ? I would have thought in the `input type` part I would simply have put

```
value=" $row['username'] "
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: your checkboxes don't have a `value` set on them..!

Comment: change this part: `"<input type='checkbox' name='check_contacts[]' >"`

Comment: to this: `"<input type='checkbox' name='check_contacts[]' value='$row[username]'>"`

Comment: Thanks, at least I'm not getting an error now. But do you know why my checked checkboxes aren't echoing with my `if(!empty($_POST['check_contacts'])) etc...` code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does it for me :

```
 //this code below will get the username of contacts
 // for $user_id 
 $select_from_user_table = "SELECT  contacts.contact_id, user.username
FROM contacts 
INNER JOIN user
ON contacts.contact_id=user.user_id WHERE contacts.user_id = '$user_id'";

    //get the result of the above
    $result2=mysqli_query($con,$select_from_user_table); 
    ?>

        <form action="" method="post">
    <?php
    //show the usernames, phone numbers
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) { ?>
     <input type='checkbox' name='check_contacts[]' value='<?=$row['username']?>'> <?php echo $row['contact_id'] ?> </br>

        <?php   
        //we need the php bracket below to close the while loop
}

            ?>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

<?php

if(!empty($_POST['check_contacts'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_contacts'] as $check) {
            echo $check; //echoes the value set in the HTML form for each checked checkbox.
                         //so, if I were to check 1, 3, and 5 it would echo value 1, value 3, value 5.
                         //in your case, it would echo whatever $row['Report ID'] is equivalent to.
    }
}

    $con->close();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to echo the form as the following:

```
echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='check_contacts[]' value='". $row['contact_id'] ."'>". $row['username'] ."</label>";
```

And when verifying I suggest to use `isset()` first before `!empty()`:

```
if(isset($_POST['check_contacts']) && !empty($_POST['check_contacts'])){
  foreach($_POST['check_contacts'] as $value){
    echo $value;
  }
}
```

If an index does not exist, it will not prompt a warning this way.

When no checkboxes are checked while the form is submitted the array will be empty and no values displayed.

Also its better to use an id as value because you can always query your database with them.

Comment: I couldn't get your code to work for me but +1 for the idea of using the id as value, making it easier to query the database.